# POSTGRES mydate column + interval with configurable parameter syntax

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query in Postgres that works for me.

```
DELETE 
FROM transaction_detail th
WHERE transaction_id in (select transaction_id from transaction_head where now < th.created_ts + interval '120' day);
```

I now want to change the hardcoded retention period of '120' to a configurable parameter.

i.e.

```
DELETE 
FROM transaction_detail td
WHERE td.transaction_id in (select th.id from transaction_head th where th.created_ts + (select retention_period from my_app_params) < now());
```

This does not work for me because I can't quite get the syntax right. Can someone help me with fixing the syntax of the second query please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use multiplication:

```
DELETE FROM transaction_detail td
    WHERE td.transaction_id in (select th.id
                                from transaction_head th
                                where th.created_ts + (select retention_period from my_app_params) * interval '1 day' < now()
                               );
```